# Bluetooth not detecting any device

Tags: release-loki, bluetooth

Im using a laptop ASUS A455LF with fresh install of elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki, when i try to use my bluetooth, no devices are found.

When try this in terminal:
`sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`

Get this

    `● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since lun 2017-10-16 12:05:20 COT; 1h 10min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 948 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─948 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
oct 16 12:05:20 einar-X455LF bluetoothd[948]: Not enough free handles to register service
oct 16 12:05:20 einar-X455LF bluetoothd[948]: Not enough free handles to register service
oct 16 12:05:20 einar-X455LF bluetoothd[948]: Current Time Service could not be registered
oct 16 12:05:20 einar-X455LF bluetoothd[948]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
oct 16 12:05:20 einar-X455LF bluetoothd[948]: Not enough free handles to register service
oct 16 12:05:20 einar-X455LF bluetoothd[948]: Not enough free handles to register service
oct 16 12:05:20 einar-X455LF bluetoothd[948]: Sap driver initialization failed.
oct 16 12:05:20 einar-X455LF bluetoothd[948]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)`

Result of `rfkill list`

`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

Already tried

1. Strech bluetooth device search window vertically
2. `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service`
3. Reinstall OS

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue at first. My problem was that I needed to expand the Device Search window because it was too small and the device that was actually found, and was present under Device, was not visible in the window.It sounds stupid, but that's what it was. [image]

[image]

Comment: Thats was the first thing that i tried, and didnt work

Comment: I also ran `modprobe -v btusb`, but I don't know what it did.

Comment: Nothing change, any other idea?

Comment: If you can, try other devices. It might be a device problem.

Comment: In Windows 10 it works

Comment: It might be a driver problem. The accepted answer from here is a general guidance, but could help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/887047/device-drivers-for-ubuntu-gnome-on-an-asus-laptop

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that bluetooth is not unlocked 
you can use:

rfkill list to see if your bluetooth is blocked if it is you can use
rfkill unblock bluetooth and it should fix it

Comment: I add theinfo, but its not blocked

Comment: install blueman

Comment: I did it, but have the same result

Answer (score 0):

Just check that your Discover Devices window is expanded. By default its minimal, and can hide discovered devices within. This should really be reported as a bug I guess.